# reload html elements flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, reload

Hello everyone!,
so I was building a flask app that displays the current time.The time does display on the webpage as intended.But,the thing is that I have the reload the page manually for the time to update.But I want the time to update on itself.Here is my python file containing the code to the website:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import time
from flask import render_template , Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True 
@app.route('/')
def index():
        while True:
                global time
                time1 = time.time()
                global time2
                time2 = time.ctime(time1)
                return render_template('index.html' , time3 = time2)
if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug = True)
```

and here is my HTML code for the website:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>{{time3}}</h1>
</body>
```

Can anyone help me out plz?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you can't do this only using `html` and `python`, you need to use `Javascript` or any other client side language. If time info will be served by python(from server) you can do it like ;

Html and JavaScript code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<h>Time: </h>

<span id="time"></span>

</body>

<script type=text/javascript>

function timeClock()
  {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "{{ url_for('time_info') }}", true);

    xhr.onload = function()
      {

        if(this.status = 200)
          {
            time.innerHTML  = this.response;
          } 

        else
          {
            console.error(xhr);
          }
        
      };
    
    xhr.send(null);

  }
setInterval(timeClock, 1000);

</script>
</html>
```

Flask code:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,jsonify
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main_page():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/time_info",methods=['GET'])
def time_info():
    return jsonify(time.ctime())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`timeClock()` func will send `GET` reqest to the server every second and `python` will get this request and it will send `time.ctime()` output to the client. Client will get this info and then it will update the html `span` element